# I'm trying to figure out how to make a square that when clicked, it will change colors

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm making a game where one of the features is that when you click on a square in a grid, the square clicked will change colors. But every time I test it, it either fills in every single square without being clicked or doesn't do anything anytime. This is what I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
board = Canvas(tk, height=700, width=1200, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
board.pack()
using_color = "red"

def color_square(event, squareColored):
    board.itemconfig(squareColored, fill=using_color)
count = 0
square = []
for rows in range(570, 1150, 30):
    r = rows + 30
    for columns in range(70, 650, 30):
        c = columns + 30
        layer1_square = board.create_rectangle(rows, columns, r, c, fill="white", tags="layer 1 square "+str(count))
        square.append(layer1_square)

for squares in range(0, 400):
    board.tag_bind("layer 1 square "+str(squares), "<Button-1>", lambda:color_square(square[squares]))
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. 
Sorry for the bad variable names and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need tags if you are not grouping multiple items `create_rectangle` returns *an unique id that can be used to refer to the item* and also there is no need for a `for` loop to do `tag_bind` as *everything can be done in one loop*. I removed `color_square` function as *you can use `lambda` to do `itemconfig`*.

Complete code:

```py
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
board = Canvas(tk, height=700, width=1200, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
board.pack()
using_color = "red"

count = 0
square = []
for rows in range(570, 1150, 30):
    r = rows + 30
    for columns in range(70, 650, 30):
        c = columns + 30
        tagId = board.create_rectangle(rows, columns, r, c, fill="white")
        board.tag_bind(tagId, "<1>", lambda evt, tag=tagId: 
                       board.itemconfig(tag, fill=using_color))
        square.append(tagId)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!!! I was stumped on this for quite a while, so you basically just saved my code. I might figure out how to share the finished game with you!!!

Comment: @codecrafter_123: My pleasure helping you. Stackoverflow is for asking doubts and questions. If you want to get your code reviewed, you can post a question over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Where people can assist you better.